# JS/React/fetch: not getting all data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

I'm building an app around the card game Magic, where you can paste a list of cards into a textbox and click a button to show card images. I use fetch and an external site API.
Logging shows no errors, but the result is very inconsistent - sometimes only 1 card is shown, sometimes 2, 4, 7 etc... I need to always render all the data. I've tried for days with this.

```
const handleClick = async () => {
  textarea.split("\n").forEach(async (items) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.scryfall.com/cards/named?exact=${encodeURIComponent(
          items
        )}&pretty=true`
      );
      console.log("response.status: ", response.status);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error! ${response.status}`);
      }
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log("result" + result);
      objects.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
      objects.push(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setScrydata(objects);
    }
  });
};
```

From the `console.log` I see everything is fetched, but sometimes in "batches", for example first 2, then 5. This is the problem I think(?) cause only 2 cards are then rendered. Is `Promise.all` the solution somehow? I've tried it but couldn't get it to work, I changed

```
const result = await response.json();
```

to

```
const result = await Promise.all([response.json()]);
```

but it doesn't work, the results are still in "batches".

Big thank you in advance for any help.

Edit, this is how I render the images:

```
{scrydata.length > 0 && (
  <img
    src={scrydata[0].image_uris?.normal}
    key={scrydata[0].id}
    alt="asdf"
  />
)}
{scrydata.length > 1 && (
  <img
    src={scrydata[0].image_uris?.normal}
    key={scrydata[0].id}
    alt="asdf"
  />
)} ... etc
```

Up to seven, which is the max. This shows images, but it's inconsistent; I want seven every time. Maybe this code could be my problem.
Thanks again.

Comment: Consider that the server may actually provide responses in non-continuous fashion, giving the impression of batches.

Comment: Yes, I'd thought that async/await would make this a non-problem but I'm missing something.

Comment: Why would that change the "batch" tempo imposed by the server?

Comment: I'm under the impression that await makes it so all the data can be stored in one variable even if the data doesn't arrive all at the exact same time. Obviously I'm misunderstanding or doing something wrong.

Comment: You have promises for every fetch and for every `.json()` call (good). Each `await` applies to the resolution of one promise, not all of them.

Comment: Why is there a `setScrydata` in that `finally`? If an error occurs, nothing has changed. But more importantly: why are you updated _per card_ instead of first getting the entire batch of card images using a `const results = Promise.all(textarea.split("\n").map(...))`; and only _then_ updating `objects`? Because it sounds like that's the behaviour you want: "get all images" -> "update the UI with those images", rather than "get all image simultaneously and update immediately for each successful fetch"

Answer (score 0):

You want to split this up into two separate stages:

1. get all the images (with `undefined` or `false` for any failures)
2. update the UI once you have those.

But what you've written doesn't do that, instead it does:

1. for each card:

   1. get its image
   2. update the UI irrespective of whether that get succeeded

So rewrite your logic a little:

```js
async function getCardImage(title = ``) {
  // do we need to do anything?
  if (title === ``) return false;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(...);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Error! ${response.status}`);
    return await response.json();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  // our function always returns "normal" data, it never exits by throwing.
  // That way, we can easily filter failures our of the Promise.all result
  return false;
}

async function fetchCardImages(titles = [], setIsLoading=()=>{}) {
  // do we need to do anything?
  if (titles.length === 0) return titles;

  setIsLoading(true);

  const results = (
    await Promise.all(titles.map(getCardImage))
  ).filter(Boolean);

  setIsLoading(false);

  return results;
};
```

With handleClick changed to:

```js
const handleClick = async (_evt) => {
  const titles = textarea.split(`\n`).map(s => s.trim()).filter(Boolean);

  // do we need to do anything?
  if (titles.length === 0) return;

  const updates = await fetchCardImages(titles, setIsLoading);
  updateScryData(updates);

  // Don't update `objects` until you're in the
  // updateScryData function: your event handler
  // itself should have zero code that directly
  // manipulates any data.
  // 
  // And of course, make sure `updateScryData` checks
  // the passed argument, so that if it's an empty 
  // array, it just immediately returns because no
  // work needs to be done.
}
```

Although I'd recommend not calling it "handle click" because the fact that you're pointing to it from an `onClick` React attribute already tells people that. Give functions names based on what they do: in this case, `getNewCardImages` or something.

And then, finally, you render your scryData using a map:

```
function generateCardElement({ id, image_uris, description }) {
  const src = image_uris?.normal;
  if (!src) return;
  return <li key={id}><img src={src} alt={description}/></li>;
}

...

render() {
 return 
   ...
   <ul className="card-images">{scryData.map(generateCardElement)}</ul>
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I get an error on this line. `async function fetchCardImages(titles = [], setIsLoading=()=>{}) => {` there's a red squiggly under the arrow, can you see why that is?

Comment: rogue arrow, `function` syntax does not have them, so just remove it (updated the post accordingly)

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be the case and removed it, I get this when pressing the button: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Promise.all(...).filter is not a function`, any ideas? The error line is `const results = await Promise.all(titles.map(getCardImage)).filter(Boolean);`

Comment: Ah, parenthesis issue. `Promise.all` returns a promise that returns an array, so we need to wrap the await in parentheses: `(await Promise.all(titles.map(getCardImage))).filter(Boolean);`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I now get the "No titles were provided" error log and I'm not knowledgeable enough to find the problem, I have tried.

Comment: You mean the error that you get when, as the text says, the textarea splitting is an empty array? Debug that: write some temporary code that logs textarea, and the result of split, and the result of the boolean filter, all as separate steps. Concise code is lovely when it works, but when you need to debug it: pull it apart into as many variable assignments as you need to log every step.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, this happens when I put in a list of cards/items in the textbox and press the button to fetch the data. The error then occurs.

Comment: right, so that's where you start debugging: stick some console.log statements in your function: does the handleClick function fire at all? If so, what is `textarea`? What is `titles` before you hit the `const updates = ...` line? etc.

Comment: Will do, thanks again for all the help thus far.